# Keeping slashes in path argument bash?

Tags: bash

**I have bash script that receives files as arguments like this**:

```
>myscript dir/smalldir/file1.txt file3.txt
```

now I would like to save the args:

```
>args=$@
```

**or,**

```
>args=$*
```

but when I try to use it, it prints:

```
dirsmalldirfile1.txt file3.txt
```

without slashes.  How can I fix this?  I'm new to bash and have homework.

Thank you.

Comment: slashes (/) or backslashes (\\) ?

Comment: How are you trying to use it ?

Comment: Have you futzed with `IFS`?

Comment: Please show your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get close to the result you see if you alter the setting of IFS, the inter-field separators:

```
$ set -- "/abc/def/ghi" "jkl" "mno pqr/stu vwx"
$ print "%s\n" "$@"
abc/def/ghi
jkl
mno pqr/stu vwx
$ echo "$@"
abc/def/ghi jkl mno pqr/stu vwx
$ IFS=/
$ echo $@
abc def ghi jkl mno pqr stu vwx
$ IFS=$' \t\n'
$
```

This doesn't run the words together, but it does lose the slashes.  To get a better diagnosis of your problem, you will need to provide more of the code in your script.

---

Independently of the issue with the vanishing slashes, if you need to save the arguments, you should really use:

```
args=("$@")
```

This saves the file names into an array, keeping the names separate and handling spaces correctly.  You can then access the separate file names using indexes starting from 0:

```
echo "${args[1]}"
echo "${args[@]}"
for file in "${args[@]}"; do ...; done
```

The notations used in the question are:

```
args=$*
args=$@
```

These both save the file names into a single string with spaces separating the original names.  This cannot be split up into the original file names reliably if there are any spaces in the original file names.  Most of the time, this is not what you want.

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't explain disappearing `/` characters (we'll need more information from the OP for that).

Comment: Agreed, but until we get the information about whether IFS is a factor, it gives some useful guidance on general scripting (more than fits into a comment conveniently).

Comment: ty
i would like to use the args like this
grep -h "something" $args
how can i do it with for ?

Comment: If you've saved the arguments with `args=("$@")`, then you can use `grep -h "some thing" "${args[@]}"`.  This preserves the original file  names even when they have spaces in them.  If you used `args=$@` or `args=$*`, you're hosed if the file names contain any spaces.  If you want to run a `for` loop, I showed you that in the main answer: `for file in "${args[@]}"; do grep -h "some thing" "$file"; done`, but you'd be better off with the single command (`grep -h "some thing" "${args[@]}"`), always assuming you saved the arguments as an array.